# passport-jwt using MERN does not shows cookies

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, mern, express-jwt

I am trying to implement jwt-authentication using nodejs and React by following https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvTjg4siRgU0HS3cANo7KZ52Wkud083TL.Here they have used react hooks but I want to implement it in class and without redux.But I don't know how to recieve the cookie in the front end by using axios my current code is

Backend:-
user.js

```
userRouter.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local',{session : false}),(req,res)=>{
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    const {_id,username,role} = req.user;
    const token =signToken(_id);
    res.cookie('access_token',token,{httpOnly:true,sameSite:true});
    res.status(200).json({isAuthenticated :true,user : {username,role}});
}
```

})

Frontend:-
login.js

```
onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const user={
        username:this.state.username,
        password:this.state.password

    }

    console.log(user);


     axios.post('http://localhost:5000/user/login',user)

     .then(res=>{
         console.log(res);
         if(res.data.isAuthenticated){

             console.log("authenticated")

         }
     })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am about to study this right now so not sure but I have seen you need to set following in the index.js (React part):

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and that's it, the cookie should be saved in the browser.

Have a look here, it might help: https://github.com/eXtremeXR/APIAuthenticationWithNode/blob/master/client/src/index.js